# How to restrict access to a server application

Tags: linux, security, http, webserver

I have written a simple server application (with an HTTP interface). I want to ensure that only calls from the local machine are processed - i.e. I want to prevent outsiders from accessing/using my server.

How may I restrict outsiders (i.e. requests from remote machines)?

BTW, I am deploying on Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers assume you've written a CGI/modular apache application - I'll assume you've written your own custom application that also listens on port 80, for purposes of administration.

On a Linux box, the simplest method (not involving having to write your own .htaccess [ACL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) system or similar), is to use [iptables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) to prevent anything but local access to your port of choice:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
```

Obviously this is better served to put into an [init script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_startup_process) that will load on boot, and could potentially be made more robust, but for your current limited purposes as defined, this should do the job. :)

Comment: Indeed your assumption is correct (I probably should have stated it in my question). I have written a C++ app with an HTTP interface. I think IP tables are the way to go. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try adding an .htaccess (into your web application) file where you specify something like:
allow from 192.168.1.
or whatever ip patter for the local url you're using (also 127.0.0.1 should be a valid one).

Answer (score 0):

Under Apache, you can do this quite simply through the use of `.htaccess` files. There are some examples of restricting access by IP address [on this website](http://home.golden.net/htaccess.html).

To disallow outside connections and make it only accessible to the localhost:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Just make sure you specify `order deny,allow` so that `deny` takes precedence. Also be sure to specify `deny from all` so that all other IPs are forbidden to access the application.

You can also specify an address range in the last line by omitting the last number group.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to 'bind()' the listening socket you open to a specific IP address.  If you bind to the loopback address, then only programs on the local machine will be able to connect (the localhost network is never routed outside of a given machine)

This will be simpler than a firewalling configuration because it is completely self contained within your program and because it is portable.

Comment: Sounds like the simplest approach. Can you explain what you mean by "binding to the loopback address"? I just want to make sure that I understand you correctly and that I am not making any assumptions.